# Need help on If-else statement with keyboard scanner logic

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Section3_Projects {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int Package;
        int Course;
        int Total;

        System.out.println("Which of the packages do you want? \t "  +"1,2, or 3?");
        Package = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.println("How many courses did you enroll in this month?");
        Course = keyboard.nextInt();



        if (Package == 1 && Course <= 2) {
            System.out.println("Total cost is " + "$10");
        }
            else  {
                System.out.println("Total cost is " + "$" + (10+ (6 * (Course-2))));
                //If-else 1
            }


        if (Package == 2 && Course <= 4) {
            System.out.println("Total cost is " + "$12");
        }
            else {
                System.out.println("Total cost is " + "$" +(12 + (4 * (Course-4))));
            }//If-else 2



        if(Package == 3 && Course <= 6) {
            System.out.println("Total cost is " + "$15");
        }
            else {
                System.out.println("Total cost is " + "$" +(15+(3*(Course-6))));
        }//If-else 3


    }//end main
}
```

Hi all, first post on this forum and hoping someone code help me with my a work problem  below.  When I ran this code with the following input, I get three "Total cost" coming out:

Input/Output

```
Which of the packages do you want?   1,2, or 3?
3
How many courses did you enroll in this month?
10
Total cost is $58
Total cost is $36
Total cost is $27
```

I think I am missing something so that only one correct "Total cost" should be showing.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: When you have `if (something) {...} else {...}` one of those two blocks of code inside the `{ }` will _always_ be executed. Either the `if` part if the condition is `true` or the `else` part if the condition is `false`.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 outputs because you have 3 else cases which will always execute, I think you could try this:

```
if (Package == 1) {
    if(Course <= 2){
         System.out.println("Total cost is " + "$10");
    }else{
         System.out.println("Total cost is " + "$" + (10+ (6 * (Course-2))));
    }
}


if (Package == 2 ) {
     if(Course <= 4){
         System.out.println("Total cost is " + "$12");
     }else{
         System.out.println("Total cost is " + "$" +(12 + (4 * (Course-4))));
     }
}

if(Package == 3 ) {
    if(Course <= 6){
        System.out.println("Total cost is " + "$15");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Total cost is " + "$" +(15+(3*(Course-6))));
    }
}
```

The following [switch statement](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_switch.asp) would have the same result, but, as mentioned in the comments, it also handles the case where *Package* != {1,2,3}:

```
switch(Package){
    case 1:
        if(Course <= 2){
             System.out.println("Total cost is " + "$10");
        }else{
             System.out.println("Total cost is " + "$" + (10+ (6 * (Course-2))));
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        if(Course <= 4){
             System.out.println("Total cost is " + "$12");
        }else{
             System.out.println("Total cost is " + "$" +(12 + (4 * (Course-4))));
        }
        break;
    case 3:
        if(Course <= 6){
             System.out.println("Total cost is " + "$15");
        }else{
             System.out.println("Total cost is " + "$" +(15+(3*(Course-6))));
        }
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Invalid package number");
 }
```

Comment: I would prefer `if (Package == 1) .... else if (Package == 2) ... else if (Package == 3) ...` (and so eventually add a final `else` with error message) ((actually I would use a `switch`, but that is probably not yet learned))

Comment: Yes, it would be better that way, I just got the easy way out

Comment: The easy but perhaps not the cleanest way out

Comment: Thanks happy songs, this was actually what I was looking for.  Wanted to see how I could run this code without changing too much since I am just learning Java.  Agreeing with the others that perhaps this is not the cleanest code, but hopefully will become better.  Thanks everyone!

Comment: Edited the post if you want to learn more about switch statements